# How can I get the indices of categorical variables in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a Spark DataFrame, using python, and I want to get a mapping for the categorical variables. In other words, I would like to achieve the same results as if I run `df['name-of-variable'].cat.codes` on python pandas. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: How did you define your categorical variables ?

Comment: I have user and item IDs that both consists of alphanumerical values. Thus, I treat them as categorical variables.

Comment: you can probably use `StringIndexer()`, but neverhteless u should share example data and expected output at least.

Comment: I have probably answer a question like this before using StringIndexer